# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when connecting to remote Docker with Visual Studio Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want to develop code inside a container on a remote Docker host with VS Code, but I cannot connect to Docker on the remote machine via SSH (ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80).

Following the VS Code instructions to use a SSH tunnel (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_option-2-connect-using-an-ssh-tunnel) I got this error:

> "Unable to connect to Docker. Please make sure you have installed
>   Docker and that it is running. Details: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:80"

I started VS Code (Windows 10), updated the docker.host (File->Preferences) property to:

```
{
    "docker.host":"tcp://localhost:23750"
}
```

and ran:

```
ssh -NL localhost:23750:/var/run/docker.sock user@hostname
```

It looked like established the tunnel successfully. I run Docker on a virtual machine (centOS).

When I opened the Docker view and expanded the Containers node in the explorer I got the above mentioned error. To me it looks like VS Code tries to connect to port 80 but I specified port 23750 in the settings. How can I successfully connect to the remote host?

Comment: Have you exposed the port in dockerfile?

Comment: I have no answer, just want to info you with the same guide, it works for me: vscode 1.35.1. You may provide more infomation as it seems not guide issue, just your environment issue.

Comment: I did not expose the port, because VS Code connects to a local Unix socket via ssh.

Comment: I did not set DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH, and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY. Is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/580

Remove the prefix `tcp://` from the `docker.host` settings, e.g.:

`"docker.host": "localhost:23750"`

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old but for anyone still looking for options I solved a similar issue on my computer using IPv6.

So in your case:

```
{
    "docker.host":"tcp://[::1]:23750"
}
```

I configured the host on the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`.