# vscode Docker extension does not show the remote containers after updaing vscode to v1.55: vscode error connect econnrefused 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

After updating vscode to version 1.55 (March 2021), the remote-docker extension does not show the remote containers anymore and instead shows this error:
vscode error connect econnrefused 127.0.0.1:80
It is worth noting that the remote containers were shown before the update in vscode 1.54.3.

Failed temporary solution: By disabling the update.mod and downgrading vscode to version 1.54.3, the containers appear again in the remote-docker extension. However, the "Attach Visual Studio Code" option gets disappeared (apparently caused by disabling the auto-update).

For the record, I did find the following solution but it did not help as I do not have tcp:// in my docker.host.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56709857/9570993

[The error I get in the Docker extension after updating vscode to version 1.55](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4sH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSCode 1.55, the problem could be [solved](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2831#issuecomment-811978510) by setting "http.proxySupport": "off" in the Settings.
Updating to VSCode 1.55.1 solved the issue permanently without the need to turn off the "http.proxySupport".

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2831#issuecomment-811864175

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is suggested here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2831#issuecomment-811864175

Using the "Remote Explorer" extension in the sidebar to view and connect to containers instead of the "Docker" extension works.